# How do I make a ListView header to be clickable?

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have a listview containing a header which is supposed to respond when clicked.

Is there a way to create a **clickable** ListView header?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot and your code for your listview? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem in putting for example *Button* as a header in your *ListView*:

```
<ListView Width="100" Margin="20">
    <ListView.Header>
        <Button Content="Clickable header" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </ListView.Header>
    <x:String>Sample element</x:String>
    <x:String>Sample element</x:String>
    <x:String>Sample element</x:String>
</ListView>
```

Of course you can change style of the button to fulfill your needs. Also instead changing the header you can also change *HeaderTemplate*:

```
<ListView Width="100" Margin="20" Header="Clickable header">
    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
    <x:String>Sample element</x:String>
    <x:String>Sample element</x:String>
    <x:String>Sample element</x:String>
</ListView>
```

Comment: @mbob Also a valid solution. Note that there are also other ways like editing the *Style*, though all the easiest depend on *Header*/*HeaderTemplate* modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by adding a behavior for ListView.HeaderTemplate:

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=ListViewHeader}">
         <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.OnShowAllTicketsPressedCommand, ElementName=Project}"/>
    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```